# How to modify this script to allow jumping

Tags: c#

So I have this script I got from a youtube tutorial because I am new to C#. I noticed it doesn't have a jump and so I made a little script to run a jump but upon trying to do things such as moveDirection, it doesn't do anything. Could anyone help me out?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Transform playerCamera = null;
    [SerializeField] float mouseSensitivity = 3.5f;
    [SerializeField] float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
    [SerializeField] float gravity = -13.0f;
    [SerializeField][Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float moveSmoothTime = 0.3f;
    [SerializeField][Range(0.0f, 0.5f)] float mouseSmoothTime = 0.03f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpSpeed = 4.0f;

    [SerializeField] bool lockCursor = true;

    float cameraPitch = 0.0f;
    float velocityY = 0.0f;
    CharacterController controller = null;

    Vector2 currentDir = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentDirVelocity = Vector2.zero;

    Vector2 currentMouseDelta = Vector2.zero;
    Vector2 currentMouseDeltaVelocity = Vector2.zero;

    void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        if(lockCursor)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdateMouseLook();
        UpdateMovement();
    }

    void UpdateMouseLook()
    {
        Vector2 targetMouseDelta = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"), Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));

        currentMouseDelta = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentMouseDelta, targetMouseDelta, ref currentMouseDeltaVelocity, mouseSmoothTime);
 
        cameraPitch -= currentMouseDelta.y * mouseSensitivity;
        cameraPitch = Mathf.Clamp(cameraPitch, -90.0f, 90.0f);

        playerCamera.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraPitch;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * currentMouseDelta.x * mouseSensitivity);
    }

    void UpdateMovement()
    {
        Vector2 targetDir = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        targetDir.Normalize();

        currentDir = Vector2.SmoothDamp(currentDir, targetDir, ref currentDirVelocity, moveSmoothTime);

        if(controller.isGrounded)
            velocityY = 0.0f;

        velocityY += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        Vector3 velocity = (transform.forward * targetDir.y + transform.right * targetDir.x) * walkSpeed + Vector3.up * velocityY;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if(controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
            //where it would send the jump
        }
    }
}
```

The lower area, just a couple of lines above this message, is the area I need to place a jump.

Comment: Not sure how all this works, but on getting the jump button, I would think you need the following - If player is on ground, just add some constant value to velocityY, and I presume that the rest will get handled by the gravity, etc mechanics.

Comment: Agree with @Harsh. Looks like `velocityY` and `velocity` represent the current velocity of the player, and the `controller.Move` method is called to change the player's position. So it seems to me you need to adjust `velocityY` to account for the jump before calling `controller.Move`.

Comment: those suggestions did not work sadly